# can't use array.count any longer

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsarray

now, when I try to nslog my array count using self.array.count with %d I receive this messageL:Values of type "NSUInteget" Should be not be used as format argumments and it suggest s that I fix it with %lu instead,. is this documented anywhere?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does an NSInteger variable have to typecasted to type long?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16075559/why-does-an-nsinteger-variable-have-to-typecasted-to-type-long)

Answer (score 1):

`NSArray`'s `count` method returns an `NSUInteger`, as [documented](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/count). If you're using a 64 bit environment, it's also [documented](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html) that those require the format of `%lu`.

If you were using a signed `NSInteger` instead, you would need to use `%ld` in a 64 bit environment, or `%d` in a 32 bit environment.

Comment: +1 Absolutely. No upvotes for correct answer!!! Reason : badly tagged question with restricted views.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably seeing the message now because you have updated your compiler, Xcode is doing more checking and issuing more warnings.

The issue here is that the size of `NSUInteger` (and `NSInteger`) is different on different platforms. Rather than add a new format specifier to handle this Apple choose to recommend that the format specifier for the largest possible type is used *and* a cast. So:

1. For `NSUInteger` use the format specifier `%lu` and cast the value to `unsigned long`; and
2. For `NSInteger` use the format specifier `%ld` and cast the value to `long`.

Doing this will produce correct results on both 32-bit and 64-bit platforms.

See *Platform Dependencies* in [String Format Specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html).

Comment: On the other hand, NSArray's `count` (in my lifetime at least) will never exceed 2*31, so simply casting to `(int)` and using `%d` should be sufficient for all but the nit-pickers.

Comment: @HotLicks - Yes, you could argue either way. As platforms are tending to 64-bit casting to `unsigned long` will on most occasions be a no-op and no-risk, so Apple's recommendation makes sense.