# NSNumber to NSInteger gives wrong value?

Tags: objective-c

I have an NSNumber `funds`. When I do:

```
NSLog(@"%@ %i", funds, [funds integerValue]);
```

I get:

```
4869222353 574255057
```

Completely different numbers. The first one is correct, so there must be something wrong with converting it to integer. What am i doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Sample Code :**

```
NSNumber *myNum = [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:4869222353];
NSLog(@"%@ %lld",myNum,[myNum longLongValue]);
```

[Why this is working?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16076218/1603072)

Comment: Thanks. I choose your answer because you provided a solution and a reason behind it.

Answer (score 3):

You have overflow. Integer is 32 bit long and is signed so max value is 2147483647. Printing NSNumber does it in proper way (probably using long).

Comment: Yes this is correct, on 32bit iOS devices the max integer value is: `2,147,483,647` thus `4,869,222,353` is exceeding it.