# Values of type 'NSInteger' should not be used as format argument Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsinteger

Can someone help me with this Issue/error I'm getting on my iOS app:
Values of type 'NSInteger' should not be used as format argument; add an explicit cast to 'long' instead

My code in Viewcontroller.m (issue highlighted on first line):

```
    NSString *imgName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"button%iop_on.png",b.tag];
    [b setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imgName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    activeButton = b;
    [self performSelector:@selector(validate)withObject:nil  afterDelay:ti];
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does an NSInteger variable have to be cast to long when used as a format argument?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16075559/why-does-an-nsinteger-variable-have-to-be-cast-to-long-when-used-as-a-format-arg)

Answer (score 4):

`NSInteger` can be a different size dependant on the platform you are compiling for.

You should use the format `%ld` and then cast `tag` with `(long)b.tag`

```
NSString *imgName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"button%ldop_on.png", (long)b.tag];
```

See [String Programming Guide > String Format Specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html) for reference