# How to change NSInteger to Int64 when you use 32 bit machine

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

My project can run in iPhone6s,but it is failed when I ran iPhone5.It is because that there is a error that data overflow when I use NSInteger.I can't revise the code in my project, because I use NSInteger so many times . So anyone knows how to change NSInteger to Int64 when I use iPhone5s.Can I use extension?

Comment: I hope that -somehow- [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16075559/why-does-an-nsinteger-variable-have-to-be-cast-to-long-when-used-as-a-format-arg) could help...